# Active Admin Dynamic Site Title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, multi-tenant

Active Admin says you can change the site title this way:

Site Title Options
You can update the title or use an optional image in the initializer also. In addition you can set the link. By default there is no link and the title is set to the name of your Rails.application class name.

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
config.site_title = "My Admin Site"
config.site_title_link = "/"    ## Rails url helpers do not work here
config.site_title_image = "site_log_image.png"
```

Also, they say you can configure titles by namespace as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "My Default Site Title"

  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.site_title = "Admin Site"
  end

  config.namespace :super_admin do |super_admin|
    super_admin.site_title = "Super Admin Site"
  end
end
```

I'm building a multi tenant site and I want the site_title to be based on the current tenant name. Is there a way to put a dynamic field in there that changes based on the tenant?

Thanks

Comment: The initialisers can't be dynamically updated (Rails requires a restart when the config changes). Have you considered JavaScript?

Comment: Is it possible to set this in the ApplicationController somehow?  I definitely think we need some way to change the title based on the User data or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this by monkey-patching the SiteTitle class.

Put this in an initializer and change it according to your user model:

```
ActiveAdmin::Views::SiteTitle.class_eval do
    private
    def title_text
        if current_admin_user
            if current_admin_user.has_role? :admin
                "Site Admin"
            elsif current_admin_user.has_role? :guest
                "Site Guest"
            else
                helpers.render_or_call_method_or_proc_on(self, @namespace.site_title)
            end
        else
            helpers.render_or_call_method_or_proc_on(self, @namespace.site_title)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Would this method not change it for all users logged in? or is the initializers just meant for the current user session?  (fyi, I'm new to RoR)

For instance, it would be nice if I could return title_text as "current_user.tenant" or something?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question but I've just discovered that you can do the following in the current master of ActiveAdmin:

```
# config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.site_title = ->(view) {
    # Return what you like from this lambda. Runs in the scope of the controller so you can call your helpers directly.
    # For example, I do something like:
    administrator_signed_in? ? current_tennant.name : "My Site's Generic Name"
  }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works for me in the ActiveAdmin initializer setup:

```
  config.site_title = proc { I18n.t("admin.#{controller_name}.title") }
```